# C++ CURL - Postfields in a while loop

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I wrote simple code to try to post data in CURL in a while loop. I'm getting an error that CURL failed to initialize. I ran the simple tutorial that given online, that works and CURL initialized, but I'm having trouble with my code. Please help

I'm new to C++ and very new to CURL so please do explain in more details how to proceed.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
  // Variables
  const char *Myurl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
  const char *Myid = "My_ID_0";

  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, Myurl);
/* Now specify the POST data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Myid);  
}


double value1[6] = {-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1};
double value2[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};


for(int i=0; i<6; i++){

  string stringvalue1 = std::to_string(value1[i]);
  string stringvalue2 = std::to_string(value2[i]);

  const char *Myvalue1 = stringvalue1.c_str();
  const char *Myvalue2 = stringvalue2.c_str();

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Myvalue1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Myvalue2);

/* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
/* Check for errors */
if(res != CURLE_OK)
  fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));

/* always cleanup */
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

cout << "URL output should be: " << Myurl << "/" << Myid;
cout << "/" << Myvalue1 << "/" << Myvalue2 << endl;
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
    curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed initialization
*** Error in `/home/me/me_workplace/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example/Debug/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000001a6c6d0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f66af5307e5]   
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7f66af538e0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f66af53c98c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4(+0x20c9c)[0x7f66afe3ac9c]
/home/me/me_workplace/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example/Debug/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example[0x4019b2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f66af4d9830]
/home/me/me_workplace/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example/Debug/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example[0x401689]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3147659                            /home/me/me_workplace/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example/Debug/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 08:01 3147659                            /home/me/me_workplace/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example/Debug/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 3147659                            /home/me/me_workplace/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example/Debug/Stacksocial-cURL-postURL-example
01a3c000-01a8d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f66a4000000-7f66a4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66a4021000-7f66a8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66aa74b000-7f66aa754000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1703998                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f66aa754000-7f66aa953000 ---p 00009000 08:01 1703998                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f66aa953000-7f66aa954000 r--p 00008000 08:01 1703998                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f66aa954000-7f66aa955000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 1703998                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f66aa955000-7f66aa983000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66aa983000-7f66aaa52000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3549154                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f66aaa52000-7f66aac52000 ---p 000cf000 08:01 3549154                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f66aac52000-7f66aac55000 r--p 000cf000 08:01 3549154                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f66aac55000-7f66aac57000 rw-p 000d2000 08:01 3549154                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f66aac57000-7f66aac58000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66aac58000-7f66aac9e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548692                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f66aac9e000-7f66aae9e000 ---p 00046000 08:01 3548692                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f66aae9e000-7f66aaea0000 r--p 00046000 08:01 3548692                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f66aaea0000-7f66aaea2000 rw-p 00048000 08:01 3548692                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f66aaea2000-7f66aaea3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66aaea3000-7f66aaeb1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548674                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f66aaeb1000-7f66ab0b0000 ---p 0000e000 08:01 3548674                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f66ab0b0000-7f66ab0b1000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 3548674                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f66ab0b1000-7f66ab0b2000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 3548674                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f66ab0b2000-7f66ab0d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3549319                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f66ab0d9000-7f66ab2d9000 ---p 00027000 08:01 3549319                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f66ab2d9000-7f66ab2da000 r--p 00027000 08:01 3549319                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f66ab2da000-7f66ab2db000 rw-p 00028000 08:01 3549319                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f66ab2db000-7f66ab2f0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3549072                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f66ab2f0000-7f66ab4ef000 ---p 00015000 08:01 3549072                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f66ab4ef000-7f66ab4f0000 r--p 00014000 08:01 3549072                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f66ab4f0000-7f66ab4f1000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 3549072                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f66ab4f1000-7f66ab521000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548672                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f66ab521000-7f66ab721000 ---p 00030000 08:01 3548672                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f66ab721000-7f66ab722000 r--p 00030000 08:01 3548672                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f66ab722000-7f66ab723000 rw-p 00031000 08:01 3548672                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f66ab723000-7f66ab724000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66ab724000-7f66ab7c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548117                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f66ab7c3000-7f66ab9c2000 ---p 0009f000 08:01 3548117                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f66ab9c2000-7f66ab9c3000 r--p 0009e000 08:01 3548117                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f66ab9c3000-7f66ab9c6000 rw-p 0009f000 08:01 3548117                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f66ab9c6000-7f66aba4a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548768                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f66aba4a000-7f66abc49000 ---p 00084000 08:01 3548768                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f66abc49000-7f66abc4c000 r--p 00083000 08:01 3548768                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f66abc4c000-7f66abc4f000 rw-p 00086000 08:01 3548768                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f66abc4f000-7f66abc50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66abc50000-7f66abc58000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f66abc58000-7f66abe57000 ---p 00008000 08:01 3548676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f66abe57000-7f66abe58000 r--p 00007000 08:01 3548676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f66abe58000-7f66abe59000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 3548676                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f66abe59000-7f66abe5c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1708766                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f66abe5c000-7f66ac05b000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1708766                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f66ac05b000-7f66ac05c000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1708766                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f66ac05c000-7f66ac05d000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1708766                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f66ac05d000-7f66ac060000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1703969                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f66ac060000-7f66ac25f000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1703969                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f66ac25f000-7f66ac260000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1703969                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f66ac260000-7f66ac261000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1703969                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f66ac261000-7f66ac268000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548409                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f66ac268000-7f66ac467000 ---p 00007000 08:01 3548409                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f66ac467000-7f66ac468000 r--p 00006000 08:01 3548409                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f66ac468000-7f66ac469000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 3548409                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f66ac469000-7f66ac4a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548597                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f66ac4a6000-7f66ac6a6000 ---p 0003d000 08:01 3548597                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f66ac6a6000-7f66ac6a7000 r--p 0003d000 08:01 3548597                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f66ac6a7000-7f66ac6a9000 rw-p 0003e000 08:01 3548597                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f66ac6a9000-7f66ac6aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66ac6aa000-7f66ac6c3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3549099                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f66ac6c3000-7f66ac8c3000 ---p 00019000 08:01 3549099                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f66ac8c3000-7f66ac8c4000 r--p 00019000 08:01 3549099                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f66ac8c4000-7f66ac8c5000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 3549099                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f66ac8c5000-7f66ac8dc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1703995                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f66ac8dc000-7f66acadc000 ---p 00017000 08:01 1703995                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f66acadc000-7f66acadd000 r--p 00017000 08:01 1703995                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f66acadd000-7f66acade000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 1703995                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f66acade000-7f66acae0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66acae0000-7f66acaea000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548772                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f66acaea000-7f66acce9000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 3548772                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f66acce9000-7f66accea000 r--p 00009000 08:01 3548772                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f66accea000-7f66acceb000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 3548772                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f66acceb000-7f66accee000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1708714                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f66accee000-7f66aceed000 ---p 00003000 08:01 1708714                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f66aceed000-7f66aceee000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1708714                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f66aceee000-7f66aceef000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1708714                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7f66aceef000-7f66acf1b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548764                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f66acf1b000-7f66ad11a000 ---p 0002c000 08:01 3548764                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f66ad11a000-7f66ad11c000 r--p 0002b000 08:01 3548764                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f66ad11c000-7f66ad11d000 rw-p 0002d000 08:01 3548764                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7f66ad11d000-7f66ad11e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66ad11e000-7f66ad1e1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548770                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f66ad1e1000-7f66ad3e1000 ---p 000c3000 08:01 3548770                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f66ad3e1000-7f66ad3ee000 r--p 000c3000 08:01 3548770                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f66ad3ee000-7f66ad3f0000 rw-p 000d0000 08:01 3548770                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
7f66ad3f0000-7f66ad401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3541039                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f66ad401000-7f66ad601000 ---p 00011000 08:01 3541039                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f66ad601000-7f66ad602000 r--p 00011000 08:01 3541039                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f66ad602000-7f66ad603000 rw-p 00012000 08:01 3541039                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f66ad603000-7f66ad65c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3539179                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f66ad65c000-7f66ad85b000 ---p 00059000 08:01 3539179                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f66ad85b000-7f66ad865000 r--p 00058000 08:01 3539179                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f66ad865000-7f66ad867000 rw-p 00062000 08:01 3539179                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f66ad867000-7f66ad8e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548542                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f66ad8e6000-7f66adae5000 ---p 0007f000 08:01 3548542                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f66adae5000-7f66adae6000 r--p 0007e000 08:01 3548542                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f66adae6000-7f66adae7000 rw-p 0007f000 08:01 3548542                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
7f66adae7000-7f66adb19000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3542647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f66adb19000-7f66add18000 ---p 00032000 08:01 3542647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f66add18000-7f66add19000 r--p 00031000 08:01 3542647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f66add19000-7f66add1a000 rw-p 00032000 08:01 3542647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4.2
7f66add1a000-7f66ade22000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1703971                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f66ade22000-7f66ae021000 ---p 00108000 08:01 1703971                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f66ae021000-7f66ae022000 r--p 00107000 08:01 1703971                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f66ae022000-7f66ae023000 rw-p 00108000 08:01 1703971                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f66ae023000-7f66ae03b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1703993                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f66ae03b000-7f66ae23a000 ---p 00018000 08:01 1703993                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f66ae23a000-7f66ae23b000 r--p 00017000 08:01 1703993                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f66ae23b000-7f66ae23c000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 1703993                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f66ae23c000-7f66ae240000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66ae240000-7f66ae259000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1708896                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f66ae259000-7f66ae458000 ---p 00019000 08:01 1708896                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f66ae458000-7f66ae459000 r--p 00018000 08:01 1708896                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f66ae459000-7f66ae45a000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 1708896                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f66ae45a000-7f66ae4a7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3544162                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae4a7000-7f66ae6a6000 ---p 0004d000 08:01 3544162                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae6a6000-7f66ae6a8000 r--p 0004c000 08:01 3544162                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae6a8000-7f66ae6a9000 rw-p 0004e000 08:01 3544162                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae6a9000-7f66ae6ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66ae6ab000-7f66ae6b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3544163                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae6b8000-7f66ae8b8000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 3544163                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae8b8000-7f66ae8b9000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 3544163                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae8b9000-7f66ae8ba000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 3544163                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
7f66ae8ba000-7f66ae901000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3548599                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f66ae901000-7f66aeb00000 ---p 00047000 08:01 3548599                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f66aeb00000-7f66aeb02000 r--p 00046000 08:01 3548599                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f66aeb02000-7f66aeb04000 rw-p 00048000 08:01 3548599                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
7f66aeb04000-7f66aec27000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3542652                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f66aec27000-7f66aee26000 ---p 00123000 08:01 3542652                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f66aee26000-7f66aee31000 r--p 00122000 08:01 3542652                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f66aee31000-7f66aee33000 rw-p 0012d000 08:01 3542652                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30.6.2
7f66aee33000-7f66aee34000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66aee34000-7f66aee68000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3542650                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f66aee68000-7f66af067000 ---p 00034000 08:01 3542650                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f66af067000-7f66af069000 r--p 00033000 08:01 3542650                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f66af069000-7f66af06a000 rw-p 00035000 08:01 3542650                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6.2
7f66af06a000-7f66af085000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3549080                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1
7f66af085000-7f66af284000 ---p 0001b000 08:01 3549080                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1
7f66af284000-7f66af285000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 3549080                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1
7f66af285000-7f66af286000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 3549080                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1
7f66af286000-7f66af2b7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3539421                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f66af2b7000-7f66af4b7000 ---p 00031000 08:01 3539421                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f66af4b7000-7f66af4b8000 r--p 00031000 08:01 3539421                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f66af4b8000-7f66af4b9000 rw-p 00032000 08:01 3539421                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f66af4b9000-7f66af678000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1703973                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f66af678000-7f66af878000 ---p 001bf000 08:01 1703973                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f66af878000-7f66af87c000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 1703973                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f66af87c000-7f66af87e000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 1703973                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f66af87e000-7f66af882000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66af882000-7f66af898000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1708743                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f66af898000-7f66afa97000 ---p 00016000 08:01 1708743                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f66afa97000-7f66afa98000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 1708743                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f66afa98000-7f66afc0a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3543844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f66afc0a000-7f66afe0a000 ---p 00172000 08:01 3543844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f66afe0a000-7f66afe14000 r--p 00172000 08:01 3543844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f66afe14000-7f66afe16000 rw-p 0017c000 08:01 3543844                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f66afe16000-7f66afe1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66afe1a000-7f66afe83000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3553596                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
7f66afe83000-7f66b0083000 ---p 00069000 08:01 3553596                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
7f66b0083000-7f66b0086000 r--p 00069000 08:01 3553596                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
7f66b0086000-7f66b0087000 rw-p 0006c000 08:01 3553596                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
7f66b0087000-7f66b00ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1703974                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f66b0252000-7f66b0266000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66b02a9000-7f66b02ac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f66b02ac000-7f66b02ad000 r--p 00025000 08:01 1703974                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f66b02ad000-7f66b02ae000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 1703974                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f66b02ae000-7f66b02af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe077e9000-7ffe0780a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe078c4000-7ffe078c6000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe078c6000-7ffe078c8000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
<html><body><h1>POST!</h1><p>URL Path: /</p></body></html>URL output should be: http://127.0.0.1:3000/My_ID_0/-6.000000/1.000000
```

Comment: And if `curl` is null? Where do you have error checking for any of these calls?

Comment: Um... Is that `curl_easy_cleanup` really supposed to be *inside* that loop ? It's been awhile since I did curl, but I thought that thing mapped 1-1 with `curl_easy_init`

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, I moved it out of the loop and it worked. 

Only issue is that the only data getting sent is the "value2", its as if it doesn't see "value1". 

[link](https://s27.postimg.org/z7lqcrc9v/Server_CURL.png)

Comment: Because the second `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` overwrites the previous one...